# How to configure AWS Fargate task to run a container that will create a cloudwatch custom metric

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, containers, aws-fargate

I need to set up a monitoring into an aws account to ping certain servers from outside the account, create a custom cloudwatch metric with the package loss and i need to deploy the solution without any EC2 instance. 
My first choice was lambda, but it seems that lambda does not allow pinging from it.

Second choice was a container, as FARGATE has the ability to execute containers without any EC2 instance. The thing is im able to run the task definition and i see the task in RUNNNING state in the cluster, but the cloudwatch metric is never received.

If I use the normal EC2 cluster, the container works perfectly, so i assume I have some error within the configuration, but I'm lost why. I have added admin rights to the ECS Task Execution Role and opened all ports in the sec group.

I have tried public/private subnets with no success.
Anyone could please help me?

[Here you can find that the task is certainly RUNNING, however the app dont generate any further action](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C0X7A.png)

Answer (score 0):

So i solved the problem. There was problem inside the container. It seems Fargate doesn't like cron, so i removed my cron schedule from the container and used a cloudwatch event rule instead and it works perfectly